# Translate pages - Missing required parameters for Route

Tags: laravel

I have a select menu on the footer of a site. Each option is the name of a country. The site is english by default but the user should be able to select one of the 5 countries available and the site should translate the text to that selected language.

With the code below it appears "`Missing required parameters for [Route: site.translate] [URI: {language}].` ". Do you know where is the error?

// LocaleMiddleware

```
class LocaleMiddleware
{
    protected $languages = ['en','fr','es', 'de'];
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(!session()->has('locale'))
        {
            session()->put('locale', $request->getPreferredLanguage($this->languages));
        }
        app()->setLocale(session('locale'));
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

// TranslateLocale controller

```
class TranslateLocale extends Controller
{
    public function language($language)
    {
        if(Session::has(locale)){
            session()->set('locale', $language);}
        else{
            session()->set('locale', 'en');
        }

        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/{language}', [
    'uses' => 'TranslateLocale@language',
    'as'   =>'site.translate'
]);
```

Html select menu on the footer for the user to select the language:

```
<h3>Language</h3>
<form method="get" action="{{route('site.translate')}}">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    <select name="language" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
        <option selected class="selected" value="de">German</option>
        <option value="en">English</option>
        <option value="fr">French</option>
        <option value="es">Spanish</option>
        <option>5</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Form appends your parameter as a **GET** value therefore laravel won't recognise it as the variable language, if you would like to keep the route the way that it is you should generate the url, but I think that an easier solution would be to adjust your route and controller to something like this:

Approach 1:

**Route**

```
Route::get('/language', [
    'uses' => 'TranslateLocale@language',
    'as'   =>'site.translate'
]);
```

**Controller**

```
class TranslateLocale extends Controller
{
    public function language(Request $request)
    {
        if (Session::has(locale)) :
           session()->set('locale', $request->language);//obtain value from GET parameter
        else :
            session()->set('locale', 'en');
        endif;

        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

If you **do need to mantain your existing route** one way of solving it would be to create the route with javascript depending on the value selected, it could be done using something like:

// attach and id to your form -> `id="languageForm"`
Then with js:

```
$('#languageForm').submit(function(e) {
   // change action route from the default GET /?language to /{language}
   $('#languageForm').attr('action', '/' + $('#exampleFormControlSelect1').val());
   // not sure if you need to specify .submit() on the form again, try with or without hehe xd
   $('#languageForm').submit();
});
```